# Why is the initial state of Zobrist hashing random?

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, hash

When generating a board for [Zobrist hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing), why are the initial elements random? How can you detect changes to elements later if the initial values are random?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial elements are chosen randomly to minimize hash collisions. You can think of the Zobrist hash as a random hash function $h$, mapping board positions to bit vectors of length $N$, chosen from some collection of hash functions. What we are trying to accomplish is this: given *any* choice of positions $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ arising in the program, we want that with high probability over the choice of $h$, $h(p_i) \neq h(p_j)$.

The Zobrist hash family is 3-wise independent: for any 3 distinct positions $p_1,p_2,p_3$, the hashes $h(p_1),h(p_2),h(p_3)$ are uniformly distributed over all triplets of binary vectors of length $N$. In particular, the probability that $h(p_i) = h(p_j)$ is $2^{-N}$ (we actually only need 2-wise independence for this), and so the expected number of collisions is $\binom{n}{2} 2^{-N}$, which is the same as the expected number of collisions for a *completely random* hash function.

The Zobrist hash function has an important advantage over a completely random hash function: it is easy to compute. Moreover, it is easy to update after a move of a single piece on the board. It is this last property which makes it especially attractive for hashing board positions.

By choosing the initial elements at random, we guarantee that whatever the board positions $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are, the probability of collision is small (assuming that the positions are chosen *independently* of the hash function). There could also be some intelligent choice for the initial elements satisfying that, but it is not clear what this choice should be, and how to analyze it. On the other hand, a random choice succeeds with high probability, which is why we choose the Zobrist table randomly.

Comment: Would the Zobrist hash only be useful to find board positions within the same game, since each game is seeded with a new set of keys?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. You can reuse the same keys, i.e., only choose the random values once (or generate them pseudorandomly with a fixed seed).